# Aiohttp json grab from a dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x, aiohttp

How do I use aiohttp to separate a json dictionary:

Example: https://fortnite-public-service-live-prod.ol.epicgames.com/fortnite/api/version Grab 12.50 from the "version" section so the response is "12.50" onlyAio

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`aiohttp` can parse the JSON data for you automatically; afterwards it's just a matter of getting the correct key from the document:

```py
import asyncio
import aiohttp

async def get_data():
    async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
        while True:
            async with session.get("https://fortnite-public-service-live-prod.ol.epicgames.com/fortnite/api/version") as resp:
                if resp.status == 200:
                    data = await resp.json()
                    print("version is: %s" % data["version"])
                else:
                    print("invalid response status %s", resp.status)
            await asyncio.sleep(5)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    try:
        loop.run_until_complete(get_data())
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        pass
```

Output:

```
version is: 12.50
version is: 12.50
version is: 12.50
```

This prints the version every 5 seconds; use `Ctrl+C` to stop it.

Comment: If i wanted to do that it many times in one file what would i have to copy and what would i have to leave on its own?

Comment: You just need to add a loop (use `for` if you want a specific number of runs or `while True` for running continuously). See updated answer